# how to create a subprogram that finds the sum of the elements entered by a user

Tags: java, arrays, element, subroutine

Here is the subprogram I wrote:

```
public static int profitCalc(int num[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i = i + 1)
    {
        sum +=  num[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But when I enter it (like the code below), it gives me an error.

```
System.out.println(profitCalc(profit[]));
```

Comment: @Abra I edited it and showed the code I wrote above.

Comment: Your code works, if you pass a valid Integer Array to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared the Integer array

```
int[] profit = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; 
System.out.println(profitCalc(profit));
```

Whole code:

```
    class Main {
    public static int profitCalc(int num[])
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i = i + 1)
        {
            sum +=  num[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no of vechile:");
        int noOfVechile = input.nextInt();
        int[] profit = new int[noOfVechile];
        for(int i=0;i<profit.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter profit of vechile "+(i+1));
            int profitPerVechile = input.nextInt();
            profit[i]=profitPerVechile;
        }

        System.out.println(profitCalc(profit));
    }

}
```

Comment: The array is based on the profit entered by the user (per vehicle).

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to calculate the entrys made by the user in the array and add them up?

Comment: Yes . updated the answer . can u check

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read values from console and then you want to find the profit/sum, you can read the values using Scanner class and store those values in Array.

```
    public static int profitCalc(int num[]) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i = i + 1) {
        sum += num[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int profitsLenth = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] profits = new int[profitsLenth];
    for (int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++) {
        profits[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(profitCalc(profits));

}
```